# Getting Commit ID in CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am using `CodePipeline` with `CodeCommit`. Builds are triggered automatically with push to `master` branch. In `CodePipeline` console it is clearly visible that i am receiving commit id but i need to get it in the build environment so i can add them as a tag to the ECS image when i build it. Is there a way to get in in build environment.
[image: This is the id i am looking for]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html) environment variable to retrieve the commit hash displayed in CodePipeline at build time.

Comment: CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION is the commit sha.

Comment: I had assumed this variable was only available when codebuild pulls the source itself. However even if it's source is CODEPIPELINE, this variable still works.

Comment: Alas only for the primary source, however.

Comment: @Unsigned that's a S3 version identifier, not the corresponding git commit sha.

Answer (score 9):

Adding an answer that explains how to achieve this in CloudFormation, as it took me a while to figure it out. You need to define your stage as:

```yaml
Name: MyStageName
Actions:
    -
        Name: StageName
        InputArtifacts:
            - Name: InputArtifact
        ActionTypeId:
            Category: Build
            Owner: AWS
            Version: '1'
            Provider: CodeBuild
        OutputArtifacts:
            - Name: OutputArtifact
        Configuration:
            ProjectName: !Ref MyBuildProject
            EnvironmentVariables:
                '[{"name":"COMMIT_ID","value":"#{SourceVariables.CommitId}","type":"PLAINTEXT"}]'
```

In your actions you need to have this kind of syntax. Note that the `EnvironmentVariables` property of a CodePipeline stage is *different* from a `AWS::CodeBuild::Project` property. If you were to add `#{SourceVariables.CommitId}` as an env variable there, it wouldn't be resolved properly.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the `AWS::CodeBuild::Project` vs `AWS::CodePipeline::Action` distinction, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 5):

CodePipeline now also allows you to configure your pipeline with variables that are generated at execution time.  In this example your CodeCommit action will produce a variable called CommitId that you can pass into a CodeBuild environment variable via the CodeBuild action configuration.

Here is a conceptual overview of the feature: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html

For an example walk through of passing the commit id into your build action you can go here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/actions-variables.html

It would also be worth considering tagging the image with the CodePipeline execution id instead of the commit id, that way it prevents future builds with the same commit from overwriting the image.  Using the CodePipeline execution id is also shown in the example above.

Answer (score 5):

Additionally to @Bar's answer: just adding `EnvironmentVariables` is not enough, you need to set `Namespace` also.

For example:

```yaml
      pipeBackEnd:
        Type: AWS::CodePipeline::Pipeline
        Properties:
          ...
          Stages:
            - Name: GitSource
              Actions:
                - Name: CodeSource
                  ActionTypeId:
                    Category: Source
                    ...
                  Configuration: (...)
                  Namespace: SourceVariables  # <<< === HERE, in Source
            - Name: Deploy
              Actions:
                - Name: BackEnd-Deploy
                  ActionTypeId:
                    Category: Build
                    Provider: CodeBuild (...)
                  Configuration:
                    ProjectName: !Ref CodeBuildBackEnd
                    EnvironmentVariables: '[{"name":"BranchName","value":"#{SourceVariables.BranchName}","type":"PLAINTEXT"},{"name":"CommitMessage","value":"#{SourceVariables.CommitMessage}","type":"PLAINTEXT"}]'
```

Also, it may be useful: [list of CodePipeline variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-variables.html#reference-variables-list-configured-codebuild)

Answer (score 4):

Is [View Current Source Revision Details in a Pipeline (CLI)](https://web.archive.org/web/20171119031917/http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/monitoring-source-revisions-view.html#monitoring-source-revisions-view-cli) what you're looking for?

Most (if not all) of the language SDKs natively support this [GetPipelineExecution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/APIReference/API_GetPipelineExecution.html) API too.